# Android How to play media files(.mp4) from assets folder

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, mp4

I have a problem with my code wherein i cant trace the problem on the second try where the `player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());` cannot determine the AssetFileDescriptor on the 1st try catch statement..

it says that the local variable is not initialized.. but if i initialized it to null..

the app will unfortunately closed..

```
package com.thesis.americansignlanguage;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class Videocompareclass extends Activity {
String get;
VideoView gesture;
int charIndex;
char[] getArray;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gesturecompare);
    SurfaceView videoView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.sf_view);
    SurfaceHolder holder = videoView.getHolder();
    Bundle gotWord = getIntent().getExtras();
    get = gotWord.getString("key");
    TextView Word = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Word.setText(get);

    AssetFileDescriptor afd;
    try {
        afd = getAssets().openFd("hello.mp4");
    } catch(IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

    if(player.isPlaying()) {
        player.reset();
    }

    player.setDisplay(holder);

    try {
        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        player.prepare();
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    player.start();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd;
try {
    afd = getAssets().openFd("hello.mp4");
} catch(IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
//...
try {
    player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
    player.prepare();
}
```

if there is an exception, the `afd` variable may not have been initialized when it comes to the second try/catch.

You can combine both try/catch blocks into one:

```
try {
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("hello.mp4");
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    if(player.isPlaying()) {
        player.reset();
    }
    player.setDisplay(holder);
    player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
    player.prepare();
    player.start();
}
catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch(IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: on my surfaceView it is only showing a black screen

Answer (score 0):

Please check question http://www.pressinganswer.com/1821030/android-media-player-error-1-4-while-playing-an-audio-from-assets-folder

> The asset file descriptor must be closed before preparing the player.
>   This is how I solved the problem:

```
player = new MediaPlayer(); AssetFileDescriptor afd =
BeeDailyConvo.this.getAssets().openFd("sounds/"+file);
player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
afd.close();**//just added this line**
player.prepare();
player.start();
```

It seems to be solution